# How to find external storage directory

Tags: android, file-io

```
static final String FILE_LOG = "log.txt";

private void SaveLogToExternalStorage()
{
    String s = tv_log.getText().toString();
    File file;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try
    {
        file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), FILE_LOG);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        fos.write(s.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    String savedFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + FILE_LOG;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Log is saved to " + savedFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This function prints `Log is saved to mnt/sdcard/log.txt` Actually the file is saved to `mnt/sdcard/Android/data/package.name/files/log.txt` How can I find this directory programmatically to show correct message?

Comment: getExternalFilesDir and getExternalStorageDirectory are obviously not the same functions. You can get a path from `file` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using `file.getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 0):

Just change following line.

```
String savedFile1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + getFileStreamPath(FILE_LOG).toString();
Toast.makeText(this, "Log is saved to " + savedFile1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Log.d("File", savedFile1);
```

This will gives output like: `/mnt/sdcard/data/data/com.android.experimentalproject/files/log.txt`

And as per Alex Farber..

```
String savedFile = file.getAbsolutePath().toString();
Toast.makeText(this, "Log is saved to " + savedFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Log.e("PATH", savedFile1);
```

Output: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.experimentalproject/files/log.txt`

He is spot on...

Hope this will help you.

Thanks..

Comment: /data/data/com.android.experimentalproject/files/log.txt is internal storage. Of course, this doesn't help.