# Directory issue in android

Tags: android

Can't understand

> Blockquote

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

> Blockquote

in Android .
 Please explain it easily with example .

Comment: Check this, It may solve your problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914225/how-to-find-external-storage-directory

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is the method that retrieves the path of your storage directory or your SDCard for your device. It depends on your device. Android automatically detects which is your storage directory in android.

This helps you to get the path of your main directory and scan or search the entire directory by using an algorithm. Here is the [example](https://github.com/protocol10/ASplayer/blob/master/src/com/akshay/protocol10/asplayer/models/DataRetriver.java) that would help you what is the use of it.